# can i reduce image file size in photoshop to under a specific size?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have to put up a 1mb image.

The image is currently at 1.01 Mb.

How can i tell photoshop to drop quality enough to put it under the 1Mb mark? Using save for web drastically reduces the image quality.

Is there someway to tell photoshop "just make it small enough"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Save for Web window, at the very top right corner you'll find a small menu icon. Click it, select "Optimize to File Size..."

Here is Adobe's documentation:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/creativesuite/cs/using/WS6E857477-27FE-4a88-B8A4-074DC3C65F68.html#WS582E9975-BC7A-421e-BCD9-200060710B63

> Compress a web graphic to a specific file size
>
> 1. Choose File > Save For Web & Devices.
> 2. Click a tab at the top of the Save For Web & Devices dialog box to select a display option: Optimized, 2‑Up, or 4‑Up. If you select 4‑Up,
>      select the preview you want to optimize.
> 3. (Optional) Select the slices you want to optimize and the file format you want to use.
> 4. Select Optimize To File Size from the Optimize menu (to the right of the Preset menu).
> 5. Enter the desired file size.
> 6. Select a Start With option:
>
>    **Current Settings** Uses the current file format.
>
>    **Auto Select GIF/JPEG** Automatically selects the optimal format
>      depending on image content.
> 7. Select a Use option to specify whether you want to apply the specified file size to current slice only, to each slice in the image,
>      or to all slices. Click OK.

Comment: as "save for web" is deprecated how would one do this in newer version? It seemd save under filesize is not correctly being respected when working in batch mode. tips?

Comment: Doesn't compress your file to a specific size, but this method compressed my file to well under what I was looking for: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mzD4cVaTQSw